# The parasitic parameters on layout

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, layout

I would like to know why using polygon pour traces could reduce the parasitic element.
the parasitic element includes L, R. any theory could support this one?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need much theory to say that a wider track has lower resistance and self-inductance. Think of a track that's twice as wide as two tracks in parallel. That will result in a reduction in resistance to half. The two inductors will couple to some extent, so the resulting inductance won't be half, but will be less than either by themselves.

The pours you have illustrated simply widens the tracks.

Note that the parasitic capacitance will increase though.

Comment: Hi Neil,
wider track equal to  twice as wide as two tracks ? may I know why?
\

Comment: @Jitter456 No. I'm not able to think below that level, I can't imagine what your conceptual difficulty might be. Look up the formula for resistors in parallel. Check you know what parallel means, like, side by side, offering two alternate paths to anything that wants to travel over them.